# Filter Facebook Checkins by Date - Graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Does anyone know if there is currently a way to filter out checkins returned from the /me/checkins call so that it only selects places checked into for the current day?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `until` and `since` with most graph queries, so try something like this:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/me/checkins?since=yesterday
```

The value you pass can be either a UNIX timestamp or any valid `strtotime` value.